# SQL Server using dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am re-posing my question. I have a simple table below:

```
Item       Date       QTY
Chair      12/6/08    69
```

I like to use SQL Server to pull these items from the `Item` column for three years prior to the `Date` column and three years on or after the `Date` column.

For example, `Chair` item, I like to know how many chairs were sold three years prior to 12/6/08; and how many chair sold on 12/6/08 or after 12/06/08.

Below is my desired output with each year and chair sold. I was thinking to use the `Dateadd` function but not sure how to write it yet. Thanks a lot.

```
Year3   Year2   Year1     Date      Year1    Year2     Year3
12/5/05 12/5/06 12/5/07   12/6/08   12/6/09  12/6/10   12/6/11
199     322     233                 344      783       564
```

Comment: Use `pivot` or conditional aggregation.  Please edit your question with the approach you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Below is just prove of concept from tsql, as I am not sure for the yearly aggregation do you need a roll up or a slice of sum

```
declare @t table (item varchar(50), [date] date, Qty int)

insert into @t
values
('Chair', '20080612', 69),
('Chair', '20070612', 7),
('Chair', '20060612', 6),
('Chair', '20050612', 5),
('Chair', '20040612', 4),
('Chair', '20030612', 3),
('Chair', '20020612', 2),
('Chair', '20010612', 1),
('Chair', '20090612', 9),
('Chair', '20100612', 10),
('Chair', '20110612', 11),
('Chair', '20120612', 12)


select t.item
    , sum(case when  t1.[date] >= Dateadd(year, -3, t.[date]) and t1.[date] < t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [-year3]
    , sum(case when  t1.[date] >= Dateadd(year, -2, t.[date]) and t1.[date] < t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [-year2]
    , sum(case when  t1.[date] >= Dateadd(year, -1, t.[date]) and t1.[date] < t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [-year1]
    , t.date
    , SUM(case when t1.[date] <= DATEADD(year, 1, t.[date]) and t1.[date] > t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [+year1]
    , SUM(case when t1.[date] <= DATEADD(year, 2, t.[date]) and t1.[date] > t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [+year2]
    , SUM(case when t1.[date] <= DATEADD(year, 3, t.[date]) and t1.[date] > t.[date] then t1.Qty else 0 end) as [+year3]
from @t t join @t t1 on t.item = t1.item
group by t.date, t.item
order by 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional approach to get the desired data.. make your desired date as pivot

Comment: Did you just copy Gordon's comment?

Comment: Ohh i dnt see that comment .. whatever